# Finding the best upper bound of $\int_a^b\frac{\sin^2x}x\,dx$ by hand

Tags: definite-integrals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, upper-lower-bounds

> **Q:** Without using any series expansions, find, **by hand**, the best upper bound of $$\int_a^b\frac{\sin^2x}x\,dx.$$

**Attempt:**

An exact expression would not be expected since we would be dealing $\text{Si}(x)$ after integrating by parts.

Putting $f(x)=\sin^2x$ and $g(x)=1/x$ into C-S inequality for integrals, we have that $$\int_a^b\frac{\sin^2x}x\,dx\le\sqrt{\left(\int_a^b\frac1{x^2}\,dx\right)\left(\int_a^b\sin^4x\,dx\right)}$$ and using the elementary identity that $$\int\sin^4x\,dx=\frac{3x}8-\frac{\sin2x}4+\frac{\sin4x}{32}+C$$ we get $$\begin{align}\int_a^b\frac{\sin^2x}x\,dx&\le\frac1{4\sqrt2}\sqrt{\left(\frac1a-\frac1b\right)\left(12(b-a)-8(\sin2b-\sin2a)+\sin4b-\sin4a\right)}\\&\le\frac1{4\sqrt{2ab}}\sqrt{12(a-b)^2-8(a-b)(\sin2a-\sin2b)-(\sin4a-\sin4b)}\end{align}$$

[This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qip1jgm2pr) measures how well the upper bound fits the integral at different limits.

Can it be improved?

Comment: In your view, what is meant by "best upper bound"?

Comment: Any improvement to the one I've found.

Comment: One may apply an arbitrary number of steps of integration by parts, then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. There are as many refinements as you like: such expression clearly converges to $\frac{2}{\pi}\log\frac{b}{a}$ as long as $a\to +\infty$ and $b-a\to +\infty$.

Comment: And if $b-a$ is large it is practical to remove the oscillations of the integrand function by considering the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{x}$ (which is just $1$) and the Laplace transform of $\sin^2(x)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(a,b)}(x)$, then implementing the outlined approach.

Answer (score 0):

My first upper bound would be
$\ln(b)-\ln(a)$.
Of course this ignores the variation in
$\sin^2$.
It would be interesting to compare this
with the C-S bounds
for various values
of a and b.

Comment: Yes that would be my first guess: $$\int_a^b\frac{\sin^2x}x\,dx=\int_a^b\frac1x\,dx-\int_a^b\frac{\cos^2x}x\,dx=[\ln b-\ln a]-\mathcal{I}$$

Comment: And then you want a lower bound for I.